# UDP/TCP hole punching vs UPnP vs STUN vs?

Tags: nat, upnp, hole-punching, stun

I'm trying to make a P2P Program and need help with getting through the NAT of the clients. I'm curious about:

1. The drawbacks/benefits of the three methods i listed and which else exists?
2. How many routers support which methods?
3. Which methods are commonly used by the big companies? (BitTorrent, TeamViewer,...)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

UPnP requires software support in your router. Even when routers have it, it's sometimes turned off due to security concerns.

STUN uses a simple public server to detect the presence of NAT and the real IP addresses. This is useful for other, higher-level protocols that do the useful work.

Hole punching is a simple technique to connect two computers. It requires a 3rd public computer to communicate between the 2 computers behind NAT. You could run your own server with a custom protocol, our you could use STUN and existing STUN servers. (Only a few packets are needed for setup, the rest are peer-to-peer).

Of course, some NAT firewalls are incompatible with the above, so you may need a custom protocol. Bittorrent does this: they use different techniques depending on which clients are behind firewalls and whatnot.