# Establishing peer-to-peer connection without IP address, STUN or TURN?

Tags: p2p, nat, stun, turn, hole-punching

Assuming each node is on a different [WAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_area_network), how can these nodes find each other, using neither: an intermediary [STUN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN), [TURN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traversal_Using_Relays_around_NAT) or other server; nor an explicit [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) | [IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) address?

```
|node 0|------|node 1|
\                    /
 \                  /
  \                /
   \---|node 2|---/
```

My use-case is to connect multiple smartphones together without Bluetooth, infrared, wired-connection, or having them join the same network. I've seen some [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) or other [hole-punch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_(networking)) tech. Is that the right approach? - I could generate a [QR code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code) but it's unclear what information to expose there (e.g., the public IP address isn't correct).

Comment: NAT uses explicit adresses and technically just masks them so your endpoint interact with local adress, but you need global address to connect with *external* router. Hole-punching is a more general case of what domestic routers call DMZ. The only how two devices can connect in network is having routable adresses... which in case of Internet are IPs.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51004291

Comment: After each node discovers their own IP address via STUN and/or allocates a relay address with TURN, then they need a way to exchange those IP addresses to initiate the hole-punching with the ICE methodology.   You can reference my write-up on this process here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8524609/104458